# Still asking whether I want to boot into Ubuntu although there is no Ubuntu partition any more

Tags: 12.04, boot, partitioning, uninstall, boot-failure

My Ubuntu partition is gone but when I boot up, Grub still asks if I want to boot into Windows 7 or Ubuntu. To put it simply how do I get it to stop asking for Ubuntu and only have 7.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/12864) has all the steps you need to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you delete the Ubuntu partition, the Grub boot loader will still be there. So in order to repair your boot loader you need a windows 7 repair disk. After booting from repair disk.

1. Open the command prompt
2. Type following at command prompt
3. `bootrec.exe/fixboot` and hit enter
4. `bootrec.exe/fixmbr` and hit enter
   Then reboot your system and you will boot directly into windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to keep using Grub without Ubuntu, I like it much more this way.

Just boot from Ubuntu LiveCD (or an USB stick) launch terminal and tipe `sudo update-grub2`, wait untill completation and that's it.

Comment: This is incomplete. Can you explain all the steps please?

Comment: OK, so I edited it for completness.

Comment: @NotFromBrooklyn Why would this work? GRUB keeps an important part of itself inside the `/boot` directory of the Ubuntu system from which it was installed. If the Ubuntu partition is removed, GRUB cannot boot anything. It would be necessary to retain a separate partition, or to use a different boot loader that is capable of remaining self-contained in the MBR (like SYSLINUX).